# Сменить имя пользователя в ASP.NET MVC без перезахода

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookie, asp.net-identity-2

Я использую стандартную систему ASP.NET Identity которая построена самой VisualStudio для дефолтового проекта, конечно доделав то что мне необходимо.
У меня на сайте есть возможность что бы пользователь сменил своё UserName.

У меня есть базовый контроллер с функциональностью

```
protected ApplicationUser _user;

public ApplicationUser ThisUser
{
        get
        {

            if(_user == null)
            {
                if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                _user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            }
            return _user;
        }
}
```

Если я меняю имя пользователя в действии EditProfile, то получается что мой базовый контроллер уже не сможет извлечь текущего пользователя из базы данных, и возникает ошибка.

Как я могу заменить UserName в кукизах на новый, что бы ошибки не возникало?

На данный момент я просто разлогиниваюсь и предлагаю пользователя снова зайти, но мне этот вариант не нравится.
Я вижу второй вариант, прямо в действии разлогиниться и снова залогинется уже под новым именем, используя функцию

```
SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

уже с новым именем, но и тут есть момент. Надо указывать model.RememberMe, а я не знаю какой был указан пользователем при заходе. Видимо это тоже можно как-то узнать из куки, но что-то не пойму как.

Можно это решить тем что просто в базе сохранять то RemmemberMe которое пользователь последний раз ввёл. Но может быть можно всё-таки попроще?

Answer (score 1):

Есть способ получить Ваш **RememberMe**, не сохраняя параметр в базу данных. Если вы используете стандартную Forms Authentication, то в Action-методе при реквесте на момент, когда пользователь ещё авторизован со "старыми" параметрами, выполните следующий код:

```
var formsAuthCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
var existingTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(formsAuthCookie.Value);
// искомое RememberMe
bool isPersistent = existingTicket.IsPersistent;
```

Только добавьте проверки на NULL для **formsAuthCookie.Value** и **existingTicket**.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `IAuthenticationManager`. Там есть два метода `SignOut` и `SignIn`.
В SignIn передается объект типа `AuthenticationProperties`и список клеймов (Claims).

Алгоритм:

1. Получаем пользователя из БД согласно `HttpContext` (У вас это `ThisUser`)
2. Разлогиванием его и меняем Name
3. Получаем новые клеймы и логиним его